# Can I connect a servo directly to arduino uno without a transistor?

Tags: servo

I am going to mount an ultrasonic sensor on the servo.

Comment: Please post a link to the servo you intend to use.

Comment: The data pin you can drive directly from an arduino. The power, you have to drive from something better.

Comment: What does a sensor have to do with the question? And for that matter, what is the question about? Connect what to what? Are you talking about the power or the signal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arduino's GPIO pins can drive the signal of most model servos directly, without any extra transistors.

Driving a model servo signal input is not the main problem with driving servos from an Arduino.

The main problem is trying to use the Arduino's power supply to power the model servo. With many model servo's, the amount of current the model servo needs to start, or when it is almost stopped is so big that the Arduino's power supply can't maintain 5V. As the Arduino's power supply voltage drops, the Arduino often gets reset, and the program restarts from `setup`.

Comment: You need a supply that can deliver current spikes and longer durations of higher current. Using  capacitors may help for the spikes.